# How do I catch varying extensions of System.Exception and determine which one was thrown?

Tags: c#, exception

What I'm trying to do looks like

```
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            Type etype = e.GetType();
            if (etype == ArgumentException.GetType())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Arguments: {0}", e.Message);
            }
            else if (etype == ArgumentOutOfRangeException.GetType())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Arguments Out of Range: {0}", e.Message);
            }
            // ...
        }
```

and I'm getting the error

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property 'System.Exception.GetType()'

What does this error mean in my context? What is the fundamental flaw in my approach?

Comment: Something tells me you aren't the real Donald Knuth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just have separate `catch` blocks for expected exception types:

```
try
{
    // do something
}
catch (ArgumentException e)
{
    // respond to an ArgumentException
}
catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException e)
{
    // respond to an ArgumentOutOfRangeException
}
// ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following instead:

```
try {
    ...
}
catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Arguments Out of Range: {0}", e.Message);
}
catch (ArgumentException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Arguments: {0}", e.Message);
}
```

and in C# 6.0 you can further specify which exceptions to catch based on conditions you set. For example:

```
// This will catch the exception only if the condition is true.
catch (ArgumentException e) when (e.ParamName == "myParam")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Arguments: {0}", e.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just:

```
catch ( ArgumentException e )
{
   // Handle ArgumentException
}
catch ( ArgumentOutOfRangeException e )
{
   // Handle ArgumentOutOfRangeException
}
catch ( Exception e )
{
   // Handle any other exception
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that.

GetType is for an instantiated exception object only.

You should use

```
catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException e)
{
[...]
}
catch (ArgumentException e)
{
[...]
}
```

You should always `catch` in order from the more specific to the less.

Answer (score 1):

You can only call `GetType()` on an object instance. If you want to keep your style (instead of separate catch blocks, as in the other answers):

```
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        Type etype = e.GetType();
        if (etype == typeof(ArgumentException))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Arguments: {0}", e.Message);
        }
        else if (etype == typeof(ArgumentOutOfRangeException))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Arguments Out of Range: {0}", e.Message);
        }
        // ...
    }
```